# Alarm setting and background task

Tags: android, android-alarms

This is the scenario: my app, execute a connection to mysql db in which another user writes data. My app could connect to db only if it's necessary, so user activate a listener and if on server side, the db contains a particular data, gives a notification and stops listening. I already have implemented the function that gives a notification, and the background service, but I don't know how to get data to send to php file by asynctask, because data to send to asynctask query aren't the same but change everytime. So I thought, when user send first request, the app writes data to send on preferences file, so everytime the background service make a new call, it read params to send to file php, from preferences.
Is there another solution?
Can someone helps me explaining how to call preferences every time the alarm activates service?
I have used this code:

In mainactivity

```
public void start() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 8000;

    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

AlarmReceiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
String userid;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   Toast.makeText(context, "Service Ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   //Only to know that it was tested and works properly!
  // Here I should read preferences from preference file and
  // call asynctask that receives json result. If it's 1 it 
  // call a procedure for notification and then erase data
  // and stops service, otherwise it wait for a new call 
 // every 5 minutes
}
}
```

Sorry for my long post, i hope in your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HttpClient in android,

see the example post to server call

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test_user"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456789"));

try {
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    // write response to log
    Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // Log exception
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Log exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Dont forget to mention

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

this the sharedpreference call

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

to get the string

```
String value = preferences.getString("key", "DEFAULT");
```

to call shared preference in onreceive is like belowe

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPreference", 
                                                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Comment: @zumrymohammed Thanks for your suggest, I did know this single procedures. Maybe i wasn't clear enough. If i try to use getpreference inside the void onReceive, i receive error and red flag.  All of this procedures, work properly if i use them inside an activity, but not inside void onReceive. I hope to have correctly explained by my bad english. Sorry.

Comment: GREAT! I make a mistake because I omitted 'CONTEST'.getsharedpreferences...Then i have changed the string and adapted my http call using json obj and it works properly! Thank you so much.